# Can't reset the AUTO_INCREMENT value of the custom table

Tags: sql, magento2.3.3

I can't set the value of the auto-increment to '1' **(table is already truncated)** the query is:

```
ALTER TABLE 'mam_color_codes' AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

and if I check the table status:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM 'ass' WHERE 'name' = 'mam_color_codes';
```

**it shows again 34**

> #### What it can be? I have found a solution - remove the index field and create it again, but I don't like it...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: try this query --- `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY id int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=0;`

Comment: I don't know what is going on, but I have dump a table and insert it again and after that run your query, now it's working. Create an answer. Thank you!

Comment: solve you problem ???

Comment: I don't know exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query : ---

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY id int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...